# Domain resolution problem between GCP CloudDNS and Goolge Domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dns

I've 2 applications:

1. Backend running on GKE cluster
2. A static website (landing page) on Google Firebase.

Both apps use wildcard domain (`example.com` for static website and `backend.example.com` for the backend) bought from Google Domains. **Firebase (static site) app's DNS records are present in Google Domain's default DNS servers where as Backend's DNS records are in GCP cloudDNS. Backend is exposed via GCE ingress controller over HTTPS using GCP's Managed Certificate service.**

The problem I am facing is that I am only able to access the Firebase application, not the other one. `nslookup` and `dig` both are able to resolve `example.com` not `backend.example.com`.

```bash
~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) > nslookup example.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 34.111.182.171

~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) > nslookup www.example.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 199.32.158.100

~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) >nslookup backend.example.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find backend.example.com: NXDOMAIN

~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) dig +short example.com
34.111.182.171
~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) dig +short www.nozl.devwww.example.com
199.32.158.100
~ ﴱ (gke_cluster-1) dig +short backend.example.com
# no output
```

If I remove the firebase app and it's associated DNS records from Google Domain, then `backend.example.com` works fine.

Does someone know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Any reason you want to use both the Google Domains DNS servers and the Cloud DNS servers?   You could simply create a DNS A (host) record for `backend.example.com` in the Google Domains DNS server(s).

If you want to use both and/or want to consider `backend.example.com` as a subdomain, then you'll need to delegate management of backend to Cloud DNS in Google Domains DNS